# GE Cooktop Model PP945 Hot Surface Indicator Stays on but One Heating Element Is not Working

Tags: glass-top-range

On my GE cooktop model PP945, there is one hot surface indicator light for each heating element. One of the lights stay on all the time but its associated heating element is no longer working. Does it indicate that the heating element is faulty now? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about appliance repair not Home Improvement as defined by this site

Comment: `Does it indicate that the heating element is faulty now?` ... yes, but only if the element is the only component in the electrical circuit

Comment: You have a possibly-dangerous short circuit in there. The hot surface indicator is controlled by a thermostatic sensor that is part of the heating element. When you replace the heating element -- which you almost certainly need to do -- that will also replace the sensor.